# librarian-chef requiring ruby2.3 fails to install on ruby2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I am trying to install a vagrant plugin "*librarian-chef*". When I run the command `vagrant plugin install librarian-chef`, I get the error:

> Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
>   reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
>   caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
>   issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> chef-zero requires Ruby version >= 2.3.1.

- Why does this requirement break the install?
- How do I make sure my setup meets what this needs?

#### Details of my setup

I have `ruby-2.4.0p0` on a Macbook installed under RVM. This is my only Ruby on this machine.

For reference purposes, I am trying to get started with the [plos/lagotto](https://github.com/plos/lagotto) repo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in that repo telling you to install anything related to librarian. Librarian-chef has been basically abandoned by the community, but if you did want to use it for some reason the plugin to install is `vagrant-librarian-chef`, not `librarian-chef`.

Comment: I tried installing this plugin and I got the same error

Comment: You need to clear the partially installed stuff from before.

Comment: But again, probably don't use librarian. Berks has entirely replaced it in Chef.

Comment: It is also entirely possible that librarian-chef no longer works on older Ruby, we've been aggressively dropping support for 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: Yeah but I have 2.4, it's asking for " >= 2.3.1". If my Ruby is already higher, why wouldn't it install?

Comment: When you install a Vagrant plugin it installs into the Ruby environment that comes with Vagrant, not the system Ruby environment. Check that you aren't on a super old version of Vagrant, but it's possible they are just shipping an old Ruby because they haven't had time to update it.

Comment: I just installed Vagrant before trying this out (+_+). Maybe they haven't upgraded the Ruby